# How to export nextjs static HTML to multiple folders?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I have static nextjs website which have 1 million pages, The problem with that is nextjs export pages in the same out folder which needs lots of ram to access files.

Is there a way to export pages in multiple folders like 100k pages each folder?

This site is only have two pages home page and posts page:

```
index.js
[postPage].js
```

In home page I used this code:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();

  const postsFeed = await db
    .collection("myCollection")
    .aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 100 } }])
    .toArray();

  return {
    props: {
      postsFeed: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(postsFeed)),
    },
  };
}
```

In posts page I used this code:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {

  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();
  const posts = await db
    .collection("myCollection")
    .find({})
    .toArray();

  const paths = posts.map((data) => {
    return {
      params: {
        postPage: data.slug.toString(),
      }
    }
  })

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: 'blocking'
  }
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {

  const postSlug = context.params.postPage;

  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();

  const posts = await db
    .collection("myCollection")
    .find({ slug: { $eq: postsSlug } })
    .toArray();

  const postsFeed = await db
    .collection("myCollection")
    .aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 100 } }])
    .toArray();

  return {
    props: {
      posts: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts)),
      postsFeed: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(postsFeed)),
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `next export` command to produce a static build (I presume you're already doing this).

To control the output path of files, you can use [exportPathMap](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/exportPathMap) to remap the routes:

```
module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: async function (
    defaultPathMap,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
      '/postPage': { page: '/new/post/page' },},
    }
  },
}
```